# Dealing with plaintext passwords in files with github

Tags: github

Some of my projects that I'd like to keep on github have configuration files that store sensitive information such as server addresses and passwords. I wish all programs had ways of obfuscating passwords in configuration files, but the reality is, most don't. Since these files and programs weren't designed with the thought of someone uploading them to a public site, this makes sense. I could .gitignore them, but these configuration files often have other useful things in them, so having them as part of the repo makes sense. So I was wondering if there is a good way to deal with passwords and sensitive information stored in files, short of getting a private account on github.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common practice is to make a `.env` file and a `.env.example` file to store your sensitive data and make a separate configuration file to store the other useful settings in.
Then you simply `.gitignore` the `.env` file and your passwords will not be on GitHub